# Duty-free liquids on a connecting flight in the US

Tags: usa, airports, airport-security, duty-free

I am going to the USA next week and want to bring some bottles of the good stuff as presents for my relatives living over there.

My flight was cheap however it requires me to make a stop over.

- Glasgow to Newark
- Newark to Seattle

My question is regarding the security issue with Liquids.

You are only allowed 100ml containers with liquid however if you buy stuff in Duty Free in the Airport before your connection are you able to get past this restriction.

e.g.

> If I buy a bottle of Whisky at Glasgow international airport and carry it with me on Hand Luggage, will I not be allowed through with it when I get my connection flight from Newark. Or am I past the security barrier when I come of the plane and wont go through any baggage checks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Newark is your entry point into the US you'll need to clear immigration and customs, which will involve collecting your checked luggage, and then re-checking your luggage and re-clearing security before catching your onward flight.

As you need to re-clear security you will not be able to take any liquids with you on the domestic flight (exception the <100ml rule), so your only option is to pack the Duty Free into your checked bags before you re-check them.

However, make sure you check with the airline you're flying to make sure that they will allow this, and what special conditions exist.  eg, Southwest have a special policy for [Alcoholic Beverages in checked luggage](http://www.southwest.com/html/customer-service/baggage/special-luggage-pol.html) that includes :

> Alcohol (wine and liquor) in checked baggage must be securely packaged in a leak-proof bag with adequate professional packaging designed to fit the proportions of the bottle to prevent breakage.

Even if the airline doesn't have such a policy, you'll want to make sure that the alcohol is packed *very* well. Airlines often do not treat checked bags well, and if you don't believe that the bottle in your luggage will not survive a drop of a few yards onto a solid surface, then you probably shouldn't be putting it in checked luggage unless you like the idea of your cloths smelling like Whiskey!

Comment: Im going with United Airlines to Newark and the same again to Seattle

Comment: The United policy is at https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/baggage/fragile.aspx The only real requirement is that "All alcoholic beverages must be packed to prevent breakage" and that they are not liable if it breaks.

Answer (score 14):

Since you are flying internationally, you will have to clear customs and re-check your baggage at Newark. You can carry your duty free purchase on board the Glasgow-Newark leg of your journey, and can then simply place in your checked baggage in Newark, for your onward connection.

Some more information is available from the [TSA website](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/assistant/duty_free.shtm).

Comment: That assumes you have some checked luggage to put it into! This is one situation where trying to get away with just a rollabord suitcase as hand luggage works against you... So check it!

Comment: i'd say some fine scotch from glasgow is reason enough to check something in ;)